# java scp file to remote using ganymed-ssh2

Tags: java, xml, servlets, ftp, scp

I am having a situation here which I need to resolve. I have to upload particular elements of an xml file to upload it to a server, managed to do that, and I created a demo method to check if the file is being uploaded to the server or not.

My xml file has the structure,

```
<config>
 <engine>
    <eid>1</eid>
    <sometextelement>text</sometextelement>
 </engine>

 <engine>
    <eid>2</eid>
    <sometextelement>text</sometextelement>
 </engine>

 <engine>
    <eid>3</eid>
    <sometextelement>text</sometextelement>
 </engine>


</config>
```

and here is my servlet code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doPost(request,response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        //response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
         PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
         JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
         String value = request.getParameter("value");
            String message = "";
            String update = "";
            Element element = null;
            Element root = null;
            XMLOutputter xmlOutputter = new XMLOutputter();
        try{
        doc = saxBuilder.build("E:/workbench j2ee/cPEP_UI/WebContent/engine.xml");
    
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        root = doc.getRootElement();
        List list = doc.getRootElement().getChildren();
        Iterator itr = list.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
             element = (Element)itr.next();
            System.out.println("Entered 1");
          File f = File.createTempFile("engine_",".xml");
           System.out.println(f);
            xmlOutputter.output(element, new FileWriter(f));
            
            putFile(f);
        }
        
        
          
         // xmlOutputter.output(doc, new FileWriter("E:/workbench j2ee/cPEP_UI/WebContent/engine.xml"));
        
        
        
         
         
        // System.out.println("hello from system");
        // out.println("hello");
        
        
         
    }
    
    public void putFile(File f){
         System.out.println("File String: "+f.toString());
         Connection Conn = null;
          try {
           Conn = new Connection("ftp.someserver.co.uk",22);
           ConnectionInfo info = Conn.connect();
           Conn.authenticateWithPassword("webmaster@someserver.co.uk", "mypass");
           SCPClient SCP = new SCPClient(Conn);
           SCP.put(f.toString(), "/public_html/webmaster", "0755");
           Conn.close();
          } catch (Exception e) {
           try {
            Conn.close();
           } catch (Exception e1) {}
    }
    }
```

Now, From the above code I am getting file created for engine 1, engine 2 and engine 3, and thats what I wanted, but now I want it to upload to the server too. and the putFile code is not working at all. No error is being displayed too, pass and user name are all fine, and the server name too. The port is also perfect. Whats wrong then?
any ideas?

## Edit- 1

Heres the error:

```
java.io.IOException: There was a problem while connecting to ftp.someserver.co.uk:22
    at ch.ethz.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:699)
    at ch.ethz.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:490)
    at Push_Individual_Engine.putFile(Push_Individual_Engine.java:106)
    at Push_Individual_Engine.doPost(Push_Individual_Engine.java:81)
    at Push_Individual_Engine.doGet(Push_Individual_Engine.java:47)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at ch.ethz.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.establishConnection(TransportManager.java:340)
    at ch.ethz.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.initialize(TransportManager.java:448)
    at ch.ethz.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:643)
    ... 18 more
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `PasswordAuthentication = yes` in `sshd_config` file of the remote machine.

Answer (score 1):

The probable reason why no error is being displayed is that you are *discarding Exceptions*. You should *expect* to get "doesn't work, but no error is being displayed" problems if you discard Exceptions. Instead, you should probably print a stack trace in the catch blocks, like this:

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

or log the exception, or re-throw the exception. Those are the three standard choices.

Comment: Ok, Yes, now i am getting an error, that it cannot authenticate my connection. But I have rechecked it, its all fine

Comment: I haven't looked at the API, but the username looks wrong. Unix usernames should not have @s in them.

Comment: Actually I am have used Cpanel to create the ftp account, and that how I connect using filezilla too. It has @ in between.